# Integration after a merger: Camel or XAware?

Tags: java, integration, apache-camel, data-integration, enterprise-integration

Following a merger of two companies, what would be the best tool for enterprise integration:
- Camel or XAware?
- or both for different needs?

It seems that there is some overlap with maybe XAware more focused on data integration and Camel having a wider view of integration (including workflow, routing, etc.)

Your comments?

What are the strengths and weaknesses of each product in such a context?

Comment: can you provide a few simple use cases...that might help us to suggest one over the other...

Answer (score 1):

I would vote for Camel. Though I never used XAware... You can do lot of stuff very easily in Camel and is one of the best frameworks I ever used

Answer (score 1):

Given the lack of more specific information, I'd recommend giving Camel a serious look to see if it meets your needs.  It has a strong community following, its open source, has good documentation, is lightweight and flexible (see [architecture page](http://camel.apache.org/architecture.html) for more information).

That being said, I've never used XAware and I am a Camel Committer/IT consultant that uses Camel everyday...